# Why do I need to install RSAT on Windows 8.1 for accessing Hyper-V Server 2012 R2?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-8.1, virtualization, hyper-v

Since Windows 8.1 has Hyper-V Platform and Hyper-V Manager built in to it, if I just enable the Hyper-V Manager on my Windows 8.1 client machine I should be able to access the standalone Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 (which I'm planning to install on my 2nd machine) right?

Then why every article I found on this suggests to install RSAT on my client machine?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this depends on which Hyper-V server you wan to manage from your Windows 8.1 client.

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2014/01/24/managing-windows-server-2012-hyper-v-from-windows-8-1.aspx) indicate it's totally possible to manage a Hyper-V server on Windows Server 2012/R2 from the Windows 8.1 Hyper-V Manager.

Now, to manage Hyper-V Server 2012R2 (standalone), it's a bit different. [This post](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/jj647785.aspx) explains how to remotely manage such an installation, either with Powershell, Server Manager or an MMC console. This article indeed state that you will have to install the proper RSAT if you want to manage your installation with server manager (point 1.2).

If you want to manage an Hyper-V server on other version of Windows Server, please refer to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632582.aspx), which has a table to explain the compatibility of the Hyper-V management tools.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I think you didn't get the scenario. I'm talking about the `standalone` hyper-v server 2012 r2, not the one in any version of windows server.

Comment: @NerotheZero True, I've now edited my answer with the proper article on how to manage an Hyper-V Server 2012R2 Standalone.

Comment: @NerotheZero does that answer to your question ? If so, please upvote and mark as answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not answer my question. I've posted the question after reading all those articles you've linked, and a lot others. Thanks for your effort though. :)

Comment: Thus, could you be more specific ? Indeed, I think my post answer your initial question...

Comment: My question is very specific, just read it carefully & you'll get it. WHY do I have to install RSAT on my client to access Hyper-V server for managing VMs when Hyper-V manager is built into it? You didn't answer the "why" part, but you said I need to install it and referenced articles/posts that say so.